# Not able to update a value of table when two value are passed in sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I want to **update** REGISTER table:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE REGISTER SET PASSWORD = (?) WHERE USERID=(?)",(new_pswd,fg_uid))
cur.fetchall()
```

I am not able to update a value of table when two value are passed in sqlite3.

Comment: Which error do you get while doing this ?

Comment: What's up with those parentheses around the `?` placeholders?

Comment: sorry guys i got it                           
actually the data type of new_pswd was  incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Hey I guess you need to do

```
con.commit()
```

If its not working please share the error you get